# Rails: Understanding cookies/log out users remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

Admins should be able to log out a user remotely through the admin console.

When a user logs in, a cookie is set with `cookies.signed[:user_token]`
The cookie is deleted with `cookies.delete :user_token` when user logs out.

I can only access and delete the the cookie for the current user that is sending the requests to my rails controller. The cookies hash only has the `:user_token` of the current user  and the `session_store` key.

Is it possible to access the cookies of all logged in users and delete them from one account?  I can't find any info on this.

An alternative way of doing this:

1. Keep track of the log-in state(0 or 1) of every user in the database. Every time a user logs in, the state is set to 1.
2. Allow admins to change the state to 0 through the admin console.
3. The  client browser requests the login state every minute or so. if the state is 0, send a logout request.

What do you guys think about this way of doing it?

Comment: 1 is normally session cookie

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, cookies are stored in the user's browser. You can't delete them. You could invalidate them somehow, but per user, it would be difficult.

Storing login state in the database should be the solution you are looking for. So when a user comes in, you do the usual authentication and then check database. If 0 you make them login. That way admins can change that one value. Also you gotta put something in to expire the flag in your session table